# Deploying python web app for wordpress site?

Tags: python-3.x, wordpress, web-applications, django-deployment

I have created a python web app using the Django framework. I wanted to deploy it online using my domain name. However, I am using the same domain name for my Wordpress site which I have deployed using shared hosting. Is there any way I can deploy my app under the same domain name keeping my website up and running.

Answer (score 0):

With shared hosting, it might be tricky -- it really depends on the specific way the shared hosting company works.

However, one alternative that might be worth considering is to use a different subdomain of your domain name.   For example, right now you might have a Wordpress site on `www.yourdomain.com`.  You could put the Django app on `somethingelse.yourdomain.com`, and then they could be hosted with completely different providers -- the shared hosting for the Wordpress site, and the Django site somewhere else.

If you made the name of the subdomain match the purpose of the Django site, then it would look pretty good to visitors.  For example, a hotel might have the main site on `www.joeshotel.com`, using Wordpress, and then a system where people can reserve rooms using Django on `reservations.joeshotel.com`.